# Make variable change after a certain amount of time HTML 5/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to web development so I'm sorry if I sound stupid.
I am trying to make variable change after a certain amount of time with HTML 5/JavaScript.
This is the code i was using

```js
var myVar = setInterval(OnScreenVariables, 100);
var myVar = setInterval(Interval, 1000);

function Interval() {
  if (x == 1) {
    i++;
    if (i > 3) {
      var i = 1;
      var x = 0;
    }
  }
}

function OnScreenVariables() {
  document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<p id="x">hi</p>
<p id="i">hi</p>
<div style="backgound-color:blue;" onclick="x=1;">press me</div>
```

But it is not working. Could you tell me why it's not working and if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? And your code looks bad

Comment: Can you clarify the variable you want to change and for what purpose!

Comment: I was expecting "i" would increase by one every second until 3 and then it would return back to  1

Comment: I just realized that i didn't say my variables but even after adding                               var x = 0;
var i = 1;    it still didn't work

Comment: I want "x" to be 1 for 4 seconds when you click on the div and then return back to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting
var i and var x are being hoisted, so this:

```
function Interval() {
  if (x == 1) {
    i++;
    if (i > 3) {
      var i = 1;
      var x = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

behaves like

```
function Interval() {
  var i;
  var x;  // x is always undefined
  if (x == 1) {
    i++;   // undefined++ = NaN
    if (i > 3) {
      i = 1;
      x = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

And after fixing that, i and x are not declared when the script is run, so they are instead using the DOM elements with id `i` and `x`.  DOMElement++ = NaN, and DOMElement.toString() is equal to a string representing the DOM element's internal name.

I would recommend using let and const (which have better scoping and less chances for unexpected behavior, and can be scoped inside for loop closures for example) instead of var, and getting in the habit of making sure you use var, let, const and plan to keep your variables deliberately scoped and declared wherever you use them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="x">hi</p>
  <p id="i">hi</p>
  <div style="backgound-color:blue;" onclick="x=1;">press me</div>
  <script>
    var myVar = setInterval(OnScreenVariables, 100);
    var myVar = setInterval(Interval, 1000);
    var i = 1, x = 0;

    function Interval() {
      console.log(i,x)
      if (x == 1) {
        i++;
        if (i > 3) {
          i = 1;
          x = 0;
        }
      }
    }

    function OnScreenVariables() {
      document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does the "console.log" do?

Comment: It outputs to the developer tools console.  It's a useful debugging tool.  You will see the "console" at the bottom after opening the tools.  Press Ctrl+Shift+I in your browser.  Get acquainted with the debugger (under the sources tab in Chrome DevTools).  You can add breakpoints to make the code stop at certain points in the code, and inspect scope, call stack, etc.  Indispensible tool for JS dev.